# LayoutChildren method is not called in custom control after upgrade to Xamarin.Forms 5.0

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp, custom-renderer

I have created a custom control which is extended from `ContentView` in Xamarin.Forms. I have layout the **Content** for some scenario using `LayoutChildren` override method in Forms. This is working fine up to XF version 4.8. After upgrade to Xamarin.Forms 5.0, this `LayouChildren` override method is not called and Content also not displayed in UWP. I suspect that, in Xamarin.Forms 5.0 layout/arrange operation is not performed for Content.

**Note:** If i add the same custom control within Grid, custom control's Content is displayed.

1. I simply created a small custom control to reproduce my issue. Created custom control in Xamarin.Forms

   ```
   public class CustomContentView: ContentView
    {
        public CustomContentView()
        {
        }

        protected override SizeRequest OnMeasure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
        {
            return base.OnMeasure(widthConstraint, heightConstraint);
        }
        protected override void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
        {
            base.LayoutChildren(x, y, width, height);
        }
    }
   ```
2. Created custom renderer for this Forms control in UWP renderer project. Native UWP control is extended from `ContentPresenter`. I have converted Forms content to native and set to content control's content. Then assigned content control to Native control.

**Native control in UWP**

```
public class CustomView : ContentPresenter
    {
        public CustomView()
        {
        }
    }
```

**Renderer class**

```
public class CustomRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<CustomControl.CustomContentView, CustomView>
    {
        private CustomView customView;
        public CustomRenderer()
        {
            this.AutoPackage = false;
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomContentView> e)
        {
            if (e.NewElement == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            this.customView = new CustomView();
            this.customView.DataContext = this.Element.BindingContext;
            this.SetNativeControl(this.customView);

            if (Element.Content != null)
            {
                var renderer = Element.Content.GetOrCreateRenderer();
                var contentControl = new ContentControl();

                contentControl.Content = renderer.ContainerElement;
                this.customView.Content = contentControl;
            }
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
        }
    }
```

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. Run the attached sample (Sample link given in Reproduction Link)
2. Added Button control as content in my custom control. But it is not displayed.

#### Expected Behavior

Content (Button) should be displayed

[Sample link with custom control:](https://github.com/bharathirajauk/MySamples/blob/master/CustomControl_XF5.0.zip?raw=true)

Anyone please confirm whether this is custom control(XF5.0) or framework side issue?

Comment: I test the sample and get same result as you. I find you already opened an [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13492) and follow the response there.

Comment: Yes. Already opened issue in github. Meanwhile, trying to get solution from other forum (stack overflow) too. Thanks

Comment: OK, good luck. I think the problem is probably caused by what PureWeen  said in that thread.